# Having SubmitButton open a dynamic url

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, form-submit, submit-button

I have a simple form and a SubmitButton. I know that meybe is a trivial question, but I would like to open a dynamic URL when the button is clicked.

To be more specific, the URL will be a search on Drive, build based on the form content, for example;

```
https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/?tab=mo#search/P5
```

where "P5" is the variable part built on the basis of the form content.

The current skeleton code follows. I am not bound to a specific service (UI or HTML), I am looking only for a viable solution:

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var form = app.createFormPanel();
   var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("termini"));
   flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Submit"));
   form.add(flow);
   app.add(form);
   return app;
 }

 function doPost(eventInfo) {

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var urlToOpen = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/?tab=mo#search/P5");
   // DO SOMETING TO OPEN THE URL IN THE BROWSER :-)
 }
```

I wasn't able to find a method or a simple example about this.

Any hint?

Comment: What kind of form are you using? The capabilities of UiApp and HtmlService differ. Showing your existing code would help.

Comment: @Mogsdad I have updated with code, but any solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

With [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app), there is no way to redirect to a url upon form submission. [Issue 1061](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1061) requests addition of the capability - visit the tracker and star the issue to get updates.

You *can* make this work using HtmlService, but you will need to convert completely away from UiApp. See [Automatically Redirecting to a Page in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315521/automatically-redirecting-to-a-page-in-gas).