# How to redirect to new html page after form submission in Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have already build a script of a form validation. I have connected apps script to google site where html form is present. I want to redirect page after a form submission and it will redirect to a new html page (submitdata.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might help you.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "<form action='submitdata.html' method='get' id='redirect'></form>" + 
    "<script>document.getElementById('redirect').submit();</script>");
}
```

Ref : [Automatically Redirecting to a Page in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315521/automatically-redirecting-to-a-page-in-gas)