# How to redirect to a website from dopost of google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have code that uses the script to enter data in a spreadsheet and I want it to redirect page after execution to website how to do that. I tried responding. sendredirect and it isn't working I guess. I tried searching everywhere didn't got anything to work. All I need is how to redirect from google script to a certain page. I am using an HTML form of calling google script.

Comment: I already look for that and never find a solution, for me it is blocked by Google.

Comment: It is not possible to redirect from script directly but, you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315521/automatically-redirecting-to-a-page-in-gas