# How to hide the confirmation screen after sending an email using a form and a script

Tags: html

I been developing a webpage and after sending an email using a google script I got this confirmation.

[image: this screen]

This is the form and the script

[image]

How can I hide this screen so the user doesn't have to see it.

Comment: Please include your code as **text** using a code block, *not as an image*.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50919151/1813169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect after processing a POST request in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919151/redirect-after-processing-a-post-request-in-apps-script)

Comment: You can use ajax request instead of submitting the form and getting the response printed to your browser!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my website.

I will share my button + hidden redirect. I hope you can try this.

```
<button class="contact_button" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="thanks()">SEND</button>

 <!-- This is how to make a form input hidden -->

 <input type="hidden" name="*redirect" value="<YOUR_WEBSITE_URL>"
```